# How do I deal with ajax based sub components in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm refactoring a rails 3 application, and want to know how best to deal with ajax based sub components?

I have a 'dashboard' controller. Which is rendered via the 'dashboard#show' action.

And I now want to have an ajax based 'tabs' component, which is part of the dashboard.

I have two possible solutions:

solution 1: implement the tabs component as an action e.g. 'dashboard#tabs' (this is my current solution). This gives me ugly helpers:

- tabs_dashboard_path

solution 2: implented it as nested resource e.g. 'dashboard/tabs#show'. This will give nicely named helpers e.g.:

- dashboard_tabs_path

Baring in mind I have a lot of other ajax components what would be the best course of action?

If I was to used solution 2 my resources would become deeply nested, and they would only have one 'show' action; this would seem a bit too verbose for my liking.

For instance the routes would be specified as:

```
resource :dashboard, :only => [:show], :controller => "users/dashboard" do
  resource :tabs :only => [:show], :controller => "users/dashboard/tabs" do
    resource :steps :only => [:show], :controller => "users/dashboard/tabs/steps"
    #etc....
  end
end
```

Is there a good rails way for dealing with this?

Comment: I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585179/how-do-i-structure-rails-3-controllers-and-views-for-ajax-based-applications

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep my controllers with very few actions, and one that only deals with the basic REST verbs.  Therefore, in a multi-show situation, I'd keep the single `dashboard#show` and have partials/layouts to handle the tabs.  My rationale is that the tabs themselves are not resources, nor would I actually perform any RESTful actions on them.