# How do I structure rails 3 controllers and views for ajax based applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering what best practices are for structuring the controllers and views for ajax based rails applications.

For example if I had a blog, which is made up of posts and I wanted to be able to dynamically refresh a post body how would I structure my application to do this.

Technically you're only supposed to have verbs in the controller - i.e. actions or doing words. This means doing the following would be wrong:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    #...
    def body
        #return body of a particular post
    end
    #...
end
```

So my other idea is to create it as a nested resource:

```
resources :posts do
    resource :body, :controller = "posts/body"
end
```

and then create a posts/body sub controller:

```
class Posts::BodyController < ApplicationController
    def show
        #return body of a particular post
    end
end
```

The url for this will be:

/posts/:post_id/body

Which to me looks right.

Does anyone else have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I have an application that serves ajax requests as well as regular page requests and I went with your first approach of putting the ajax action in the body of the resource controller.

Personally I like this approach better because it keeps the controllers manageable.  With your second idea of creating it as a nested resource you end up having a lot of controllers that just perform a single ajax action.  I would prefer I high cohesion solution where everything about Posts is done in the PostsController vs. creating lots of single action sub controllers.

Comment: The trouble is 'blog' isn't really an action (in the verb sense) and so breaks the whole idea of performing actions on objects. Read my response to @jonnii. I've looked at quite a lot of code on Github and lots of programmers break the convention of verb based actions. However, to me it just feels like a bit of a hack, and so defeats the point of a framework if you're going to be putting things in ad-hoc places.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need just the body? Why don't you return the entire post and just use the body?

If that's not good enough you could do something like this

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  # set some etag stuff up so we don't have to request this again if it hasn't changed 
  response.last_modified = @post.created_at.utc
  response.etag = @post

  return head :not_modified unless request.fresh?(response)
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.js { render :json => @post.to_json(:only => params[:select]) }
  end
end
```

There are a few possible problems with this above code. Firstly, I can't remember off the top of my head if `find()` returns a chainable query, secondly, for safety you should probably sanitize `fields` so it only returns a white list of fields (you can do this with `slice`).

I hope this helps!

Comment: The blog example I gave is simplified version of a (much bigger) problem I have with rails.

Comment: The bigger problem is how can I view the same object from different angles. For example if you take a collection of posts (by default) you have the 'index' action, now how can I view that index as a search result or as a list of tick boxes so I can select the posts I want for further processing. There just isn't an obvious place for these use cases in rails. And the whole point of a framework is to provide a structure to place things. I think rails assumes a far too strong correlation between the models and the controllers.

Comment: Your question sounds more like "how to design a restful api", and nothing specific to rails. There's no correlation between models and controllers in rails, you can have a controller without a model and a model without a controller.

Comment: In regards to a search, there's nothing stopping you from doing: `posts/index?search=trololol`. You can then show a different view in the controller for search specific stuff, or you can have a dedicated `posts/search` action.

Comment: I agree! There does not necessarily need to be a correlation - but I think rails **assumes** too much there will be a correlation, and bases too many of their design decisions around it. Anything out side this correlation things become awkward. Yes; I can create the application - but I sometimes feel I'm flogging a dead horse, and there doesn't seem to be a big win for rails.

Comment: Perhaps another way to phrase my question is how in rails can I have a resource with many parts. The solution would be to use nested resources; however you'll end up with sparse source code spread over lots of nested directories and the automatically generated helpers will become long and verbose. Have a look at previous question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519617/how-do-i-deal-with-ajax-based-sub-components-in-rails-3

Comment: In that question, tabs would be a resource. Why does it have to be nested?

Comment: Technically it doesn't, however I think it makes sense (especially in a large project) to group things together in their own name space. The logical way to this is in a hierarchy that shows "parts of" relation ships. So for example if I was to have different sorts of 'tabs' the names wouldn't clash, so for example I could have my 'tabs' in my dashboard and my 'tabs' in my "select picture" dialog.

Comment: Then make the controller name `DashboardTabsController`. If you're concerned about the url you can set a prefix in your `routes.rb`. Nesting your routes unnecessarily will just cause you pain in the long run.